# Get value of dxHtmlEditor with mentions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a specific question, but maybe someone can help me. I'm using this input field in my html: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/19_1/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxHtmlEditor/.

I'm using it, because I needed an input field, that supports mentions. Now if I select a mention and then output the value of the input field, the mention is not shown, because its not plain text, its a span. Does anyone has an idea?

Here is the demo of the edior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5exohg?file=index.html